# How should I properly compare two dates?

Tags: java, date-comparison

Having some trouble implementing this simple task.

Basically I want to compare two dates(some older date vs new date). I want to know if the older date is more than x months old and y days old.

```
int monthDiff = new Date().getMonth() - detail.getCdLastUpdate().getMonth();
int dayDiff = new Date().getDay() - detail.getCdLastUpdate().getMonth();
System.out.println("\tthe last update date and new date month diff is --> " + monthDiff);
System.out.println("\tthe last update date and new date day diff is --> " + dayDiff);
```

If older date is 2012-09-21 00:00:00.0, currently, it will return negative numbers. I need to find out if the older date is EXACTLY 6 months and 4 days before new Date(). I'm thinking of using absolute values of both but just can't brain today.

Edit: I know about joda but I cannot use it. I must use Java JDK.
Edit 2: I'll try out the methods listed, if all failed I'll use Joda.

Comment: You definitely have to compare absolute Dates.

Comment: @user2266098 with month i think it is ok using the abs(), but what about the day, different months have different number of days :(

Comment: If the older date is 21st and today is the 17th, you calculate 17 minus 21. How do you expect that to be positive?

Comment: I thought you need the difference of two dates in months and days. Have a look at JodaTime: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JDK dates](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) have before and after methods, returning boolean, to accomplish your task:

```
Date now = new Date();
Calendar compareTo = Calendar.getInstance();
compareTo.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
compareTo.add(Calendar.DATE, -4);
if (compareTo.getTime().before(now)) {
   // after
} else {
   // before or equal 
}
```

Comment: this functions i know, problem is i NEED to know if the older date is 6months+4days ago(exactly)...

Comment: @JoeChen then state it in your question, please.

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect Mr Chen's comment

Comment: @hd1 strangely, Calendar.DAY does not exist!?

Comment: I'd personally use joda for this, but it should be DATE, will update

Comment: @JoeChen That's because the same constant are used for Calendar.get() and Calendar.set(), so instead of just DAY, you have DAY_OF_MONTH, DAY_OF_YEAR and DAY_OF_WEEK. All have the same meaning when given to add() (and DATE is an alias for DAY_OF_MONTH).

Comment: If you only want to compare dates, you have to set the hour of day, minute, second and millisecond fields to zero.

Answer (score 4):

The best way I can think of is to use [Joda-Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Example from their site:

```
Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
int days = d.getDays();
```

Or number of months:

```
Months m = Months.monthsBetween(startDate, endDate)
int months = m.getMonths();
```

where:

```
DateTime startDate =  new DateTime(/*jdk Date*/);
DateTime endDate =  new DateTime(/*jdk Date*/);
```

Comment: I would use joda myself, but OP seems to want the JDK Date classes.

Comment: @hd1 I see no evidence in the question that the OP is even aware of jodatime

Answer (score 2):

Sigh, it is up to me to add the inevitable "use JodaTime" answer.

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) gives you specific data types for all significant time distances.

```
Date yourReferenceDate = // get date from somewhere
int months = Months.monthsBetween(
                       new DateTime(yourReferenceDate),
                       DateTime.now()
             ).getMonths();
```